# how can I convert svg hexdump file to a readable xml file?

Tags: image-processing, svg, hexdump

I am currently working with `svg` files, but the files cannot be edited as `xml` files (as text). If I open the file in sublime in `Ubuntu`, it appears as a `hexdump` file. And if I open the file in sublime in `Windows`, it appears as something not readable.

See image bellow:

[image: How file looks in Ubuntu and Windows]

Is there anyway to convert this file to a readable xml/svg file?

Comment: where did you get those "svg"-files?

Comment: This is **not** an SVG file. It may have been compressed (but I don't recognize the header) or damaged in transit. More likely is that it never was an SVG file to begin with. Ask the person from who you got this.

Answer (score 1):

From the dump, it looks like these are most likely `.svgz` files (gzipped SVG files).  Try running them through `gunzip`.